# Unknown Expectation Characterization

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

I was working a problem recently and the solution invoked the following identity for discrete random variables X and Y:

$$E[X | Y = 5] = \sum_{x \in X} x \, P[X = x | Y = 5 ] = \sum_{x \in X} P[X \geq x | Y = 5].$$

Is this so? They seem to refer to it as the ‘survival formula’. I googled but didn’t find anything and a proof is not immediate to me.

If it matters, X and Y were geometric. X was number of rolls of a die to get a 6 and Y was number of rolls to get an even number.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Alternative_formula_for_expected_value You can refer to this and apply to your problem. Conditional probability just a probability, so it also share the similar properties.

Comment: This holds true. Simply replace the subscript $x\in X$ by $x\in$... whatever you like which is not $x$, $X$ or $Y$.

Comment: Thank you BGM and Did. If either of you want to post your comments as an answer I will accept so it doesn’t show my question as being unanswered.